# mysqli subquery string didn't works

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a mysql query which doesn't work. It gives me the following error:

> mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

my sql query is:

```
$select = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT title FROM category WHERE id LIKE (SELECT categorie_id FROM categories_sub WHERE file LIKE '".$site."')")
```

Comment: `$sql` has to be an instance of MySQLi. Are you instantiating it?

Comment: `$sql` <= if that isn't your DB connection variable, then that could be an issue.

Comment: this is my database connection variable.

Comment: So, what does your DB connection code look like? That error doesn't pop up for nothing. Are you using it from a class? Plus, from what I saw in your other questions, all seem to be OK, up to this.

Comment: ok it works. the reason for the error was, i have mistake use a incorrect database name.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. Always use as much error reporting codes as possible when in development. That would have signaled the error right way. Some just use `die("There was an error.");` instead of check for real errors such as `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` or `mysqli_error()` or `mysql_error()` depending on the API used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will not work, what your query is doing

```
WHERE id LIKE (SELECT categorie_id FROM categories_sub WHERE file = 'some val')
```

This is similar as

```
WHERE id = {multiple categorie_id}
```

when the subquery has more than one categorie_id and this will return error.

So replace

```
category WHERE id LIKE
```

to

```
category WHERE id IN ( ...
```

Comment: my query looks like `"SELECT title FROM category WHERE id IN (SELECT categorie_id FROM categories_sub WHERE file LIKE '".$site."')"` but it still not working. The Error is the same ..

Answer (score 0):

This error tends to mean that you didn't connect correctly to the database.  Double check your connection.  Also, `file LIKE 'x'` is equivalent to `file='x'`.  To search for a string containing 'x', use `file LIKE '%x%'`.

Edit:  The other answers are right that you need to use `IN` instead of `LIKE` for the first one (i.e. a member of the set defined on another query)